# Vector drawable scaling in ImageView on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I got a kind of schematic presentation of data that is stored as a vector drawable, obtained from an original image in SVG format. I need to zoom it in and out, but after changing `scaleX` and `scaleY` parameters the image gets blurry. Can you help me change image's size with a kind of redrawing after that to make text and other elements look not like overzoomed PNG.

My code:

```
imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view).apply {
    scaleX = 3f
    scaleY = 3f
    invalidate()
}
```

Comment: How are you displaying the SVG in the `ImageView`? Android does not support SVG natively.

Comment: via the src attribute after importing SVG via Drawable -> New -> Vector Asset

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view).apply {
scaleX = 3f
scaleY = 3f
invalidate()
setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width * scaleX, height * scaleY, true))
```

}